# RuntimeWarning: Failed to decode a serialized output from CoreNLP server. An incomplete or empty object will be returned

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am parsing (getting constituency tree) IMDB dataset using CoreNLP server with Shift-Reduce parser. For few sentences it gives a warning which is:

`RuntimeWarning: Failed to decode a serialized output from CoreNLP server. An incomplete or empty object will be returned. warnings.warn("Failed to decode a serialized output from CoreNLP server. An incomplete or empty object will be returned.", \`

I really don't have any idea why it is giving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update stanford-corenlp-4.0.0 to 4.1.0 (which is latest at the time of posting) and it worked.